# Conditional statements for aliases

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to add variation to different aliases, without having to rewrite the entire command:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['test'])
async def example(ctx)
    if alias=='test':
        #do something first
    else:
        #run command
```

**Possible Solutions:**

The error is the naming of the statement. I Have tried using `command.aliases` and `aliases`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can look into `ctx.message.content` how the command was invoked and base your condition on that. `if ctx.message.content.startswith(prefix+"test")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available as [`ctx.invoked_with`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with)

> The command name that triggered this invocation. Useful for finding out which alias called the command.

Answer (score 0):

```py
ctx.message.content.split(' ')[0].strip(ctx.prefix)
```

Is a pretty good way to get the invoked command, so you could do something like

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['test'])
async def example(ctx):
    command_ran = ctx.message.content.split(' ')[0].strip(ctx.prefix)
    if command_ran == 'test':
        #do something first
    else:
        #run command
```